# How to star a file in Gnome?

Tags: linux, files, gnome, gui

How can I star a file so that it appears in the Starred section of the Gnome File Explorer? I searched the official gnome guide https://help.gnome.org/search?q=star but it does not tell me how to star.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I was wondering the same. Apparently you drag the file into the "starred" label.

In the starred folder, the context menu provides the "Unstar" option.

Comment: Thanks! However, this seems to work not with all files (e.g. i couldn't star files under /etc but under /home it worked)